# Pass variable from called Mako template to inherited template

Tags: python, cherrypy, mako

I am using CherryPy with Mako templates. I am trying to work out how to pass aruguments from the initial call (in this example `title`):

```
class Landing(object):
    def index(self):
        tmpl = lookup.get_template("index.html")
        return tmpl.render(title="Hello World")
    index.exposed = True
```

to `index.html`:

```
<%inherit file="base.html"/>
<%def name="title()">$(title)</%def>
this is the body content
```

and then to the inherited `base.html` template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>$(self.title())</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>$(parent.title())</h1>
        ${self.body()}
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried `self.title` and `parent.title` and neither work. How does I pass the variable from the initial call?

Comment: ${title} should work. So use curly brackets instead of regular ones. And it is not a function call, so remove the () at the end.

Comment: You probably also want to change name="title()" into name="${title}"

Comment: @basvandenberg thanks, that was it! If you add it as an answer I'll accept it. I tried replacing title() with ${title} but I got the error: `mako.exceptions.CompileException: Attibute 'name' in tag 'def' does not allow embedded expressions in file 'template/index.html' at line: 2 char: 1`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that the 'name' attribute is within a mako tag instead of a regular html tag. I am not sure if you can use a variable to set an attribute of a mako tag.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the rendered variables - you use them with `${ title }` not `$( title )`